# Symfony 2.7 findOneBy() Function Finds the Wrong Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, arraycollection

I've got a controller action that's supposed to be looking for semi-duplicate entries in a collection, and removing them from that Entity's list.  New ones should not have an ID yet, and existing ones do, so I'm running `findOneBy()` with an array of parameters to match on (leaving out ID).

I am baffled and deeply troubled by the error I am getting, where it finds the wrong entity!  I've got some relevant code below, I hope this is just a dream or a silly mistake, I can't reproduce the output on my own windows development environment, but my co-worker was testing on his mac, and was getting errors, so I went on his machine and did some quick echoing to see what was going on.  See the code and the result below.

**CODE**

```
foreach($entity->getTechnicians() as $tech) {
  //find new addtions, see if they exist
  if (!$tech->getId()) {
    echo "Technician " . $tech->getFirstName() . " has no ID, trying to find one that does<br/>";
    $found = $em->getRepository('TechnicianBundle:Technician')->findOneBy(array(
      'firstName' => $tech->getFirstName(),
      'lastName' => $tech->getLastName(),
      'email' => $tech->getEmail(),
      'residentEngineer' => $tech->getResidentEngineer(),
      'officeNumber' => $tech->getOfficeNumber()
    ));

    //if one with an ID already exists
    if ($found) {
      echo "found technician " . $found->getFirstName() . " that already has id " . $found->getId() . "<br/>";
     ...
```

**OUTPUT**

> Technician **Four** has no ID, trying to find one that does
>     found technician **khjvuov** that already has id **7**

Comment: Can you post your entity code with relevant attributes and getters? Is your output always the same (if you comment out removeTechnician and addTechnician methods)?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: [link](https://gist.github.com/Bango1999/8e1e161c91f7b57e2d71) Not sure if the validator callback is relevant, so I left it in.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No errors, I was wrong to say errors, just bugs, seeing it not do what its supposed to be doing.  Will update when I have my coworker test commenting out the add/remove/set methods. Thanks again

Comment: @e1dar without the add/remove methods, we get a symfony error

attempted to call getid on class doctrine/orm/persistentCollection.

Leaving them in, we get no error.

Comment: @Bango Sorry I meant if you comment methods in your code snippet you edited earlier, e.g. _$entity->removeTechnician($tech);_ and others. And if you print all parameters you pass into _findOneBy_, they are OK?

Comment: Here is an output gist with add/remove setters called, and all parameters in the echoes.
[link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/65e25fdd9d5f55aa7c60)

Without add/remove methods, it works fine, but for good reason, because it's not resolving soft duplicates like i want it to. so the issue is not fixed, its rather avoided altogether as one might expect from removing those calls. @e1dar

Comment: Is only the `firstName` field not correct? Or are all other fields also not corresponding?

Comment: @Bango Have you solved your problem? What was the cause?

Comment: @Wilt All the fields are incorrect.

Comment: @e1dar No I have not made any changes since the last time we spoke, I will post an update when I look into your iterator suggestion.  Thanks again for the help.  I just don't see how the pointer could change from calling findOneBy() to using its returned entity in an if statement, to referencing it to get variables...  should it not be the same in all 3 cases??

Comment: Did you try what @e1dar suggested in his answer. The `getIterator` method is there in the `Collection` class for a reason...

Comment: My issue was much deeper than iterators, I still don't fully understand it.  Something was happening internally, where it would call a single update query on one of my entity rows, totally changing the entity to another entity.  I was NOT doing this in the code, it was happening automatically.

So when I ran a findoneby, it must've found the correct entity information in the DB, but at the controller level, it was already changed.

I ended up scrapping this and going with a solution thats worked for me before, having 2 form elements for new and existing techs rather than all in a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it's not a findOneBy() issue.

If without add/remove calls it works, it may be caused by modified current pointer of *ArrayCollection* so when $tech->getFirstName() is called it actually points to another entry.

You may try to iterate your collection like this:

```
$iterator = $entity->getTechnicians()->getIterator();
while ($iterator->valid()) {
  $tech = $iterator->current();

  ... $entity->addTechnician()/$entity->removeTechnician()

  $iterator->next();
}
```

It will create new [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) object, so you can modify underlying object preserving ArrayCollection's internal pointer.

This may be obsolete if you are running PHP7 ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) - Note box)

Comment: See my question comment for more info, you were close, its not a findOneBy issue, it was an issue with an entity being (automatically) modified but not flushed yet, so it found the right entity in the DB, but when it returned to the controller, it had the new values in it.  That's the best explanation I can come up with, I was hacking the collection prototyping hardcore to begin with, trying to force a lot of things to happen in the controller that conflicted with what it felt like it was supposed to be doing.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the `findOneBy()` method uses the [`load()` method of the Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Persisters.BasicEntityPersister.html#554-584).

In the doc, the parameter `$criteria` is described as such :

`@param array $criteria The criteria by which to load the entity.`

You should probably dig deeper into Doctrine API to make sure, but there is a big chance that in the array you are passing as an argument, only the first *key => value* pair is taken into account (in your example, 'firstName' => $tech->getFirstName()).

If this is the case, you'll probably need to add your own custom method in your entity repository, one that would allow you to query your database with more advanced statements (using `OR/AND` or `LIKE()` in  SQL for instance).

Comment: If it takes "first key => value pair", then it should look like _->findOneBy(array('firstName' => 'Four'))_. Why a technician with name "khjvuov" is the result then? Also _findOneBy_ [supports](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database) an array notation.

Comment: Yes it does support an array notation in order to receive the query parameter as well as other options (order by etc.) but that doesn't mean that it translates an array of parameters into `AND` statements. The result 'khjvuov' would mean that a user was found with such first name.

Comment: I disagree. Array is processed by `implode(" AND ", $conditions)`, see  `getSelectConditionSQL` function inside `Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister`

Comment: Well spotted, my bad !